# SOAP request to API not working - Laravel

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, api, soap

I have this SOAP request done in nodejs and it's working fine:

```
await soap
        .createClientAsync(wsdlURL)
        .then(async instance => {
            const wsseopts = {
                passwordType,
                hasNonce: true,
                hasTimeStamp: false
            };
            const wsse = new soap.WSSecurity(user, pass, wsseopts);
            instance.setSecurity(wsse);
            client = instance;
        })
        .then(async () => {
            return await client
                .getFunction({
                    token
                })
                .then(async response => {

                    const data =  await client.getFunctionSecond({
                        token,
                        param1,
                        param2
                    });
                });
           
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.warn(err);
            return false;
        });
```

I tried doing this in Laravel but the API returns an error, it let's me connect with the SOAPClient but it fails when trying to execute the "getFunction"

```
 $options = [
            'login' => $login,
            'password' => $password,
            'authentication' => $authentication,
            'trace' => true
        ];
        
        $wsseopts = array(
            'passwordType' => 'PasswordText',
            'hasNonce' => true,
            'hasTimeStamp' => false
        );
        
        $wsse = new SoapHeader('http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd', 'Security', $wsseopts, false);
    

        $client = new SoapClient($url, $options);

        $client->__setSoapHeaders($wsse);


        $response = $client->getFunction([ //IT CRASHES HERE
            'token' =>  $token
        ]);
        
        $response2 = $client->getFunctionSecond([
            ...
        ]);
```

Maybe it's something related to the headers, I was unclear about how to set them as it is in Nodejs, but I didn't find the solution.

Comment: Any errors you are getting?

Comment: If you are using Laravel, why aren't you using a simpler package like [soap](https://github.com/ricorocks-Digital-Agency/soap) build using Laravel?

Comment: I also don't see `$token` defined anywhere?